import a function with zero argument
defmodule F do
  def ff do
    IO.puts(123)
  end
end

defmodule G do
  import F

  def g do
    ff
  end
end

G.g()



error: undefined variable "ff"

Why is ff not callable?

what version of elixir you are using? You should get a warning in console about using parenthesis for function calls and it should work without any problems.

Elixir 1.16.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)

I put it in a single source.ex and ran elixir source.ex


From the syntax reference for non-qualified calls:

Parentheses are required for zero-arity calls (i.e. calls without arguments), to avoid ambiguity with variables.


The correct syntax is:
def g do
  ff()
end

